# Check properties ant file in a target

Tags: java, ant, properties, target

I'm a novice in Java.
In my Ant file, I would like to create a target "init" which checks if the properties declared exist (else it affects them a default value), but I don't have any idea how to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you'd think.  Just set them in the init target.  In Ant, setting properties is "first setter wins" - if they are already set, the setting in the init target will be ignored.

There are several ways to set properties, but the most commonly used is:

```
<property name="foo" value="dist"/>
```

Comment: Ok, effectively, it's easier I thought. Thank you